# Given a facebook ID, what metrics can I use to mark the profile as fake?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am running a photo contest on my facebook page via a third party app (shortstack). 
The grand prize is supposed to be given to the person with maximum number of Votes.
Each vote is mapped to a facebook ID, which is available to me via shortstack. The problem is that there are too many votes from fake profiles, I inferred this by manually looking at number of friends of the facebook profiles of people who had been voting (I have their facebook Ids). 
I am also aware that I can extract out only the publicly shared information of these users via the opengraph.

In short, how should I go about marking all the votes in two categories "Genuine" and "Fake", after subjecting all the IDs to a certain logic that uses information out of the publicly shared user info for that Id?

As an example, let us assume number of friends a particular profile is the only metric that would be used to identify if a profile is fake or not. Now there would be that magical benchmark (number of friends) above which a profile can be considered genuine and below which all the profiles can be considered fake, although there could be some fake people above this benchmark and some genuine fellas below it. In our case, these metrics would also consist of other information a user shares via the opengraph, values and patterns of these parameters being different for genuine and fake users. The point is that I am sure that eliminating fake profiles is very common problem  faced by people conducting contests,as they would like to choose the winner on basis of contestant's ability to spread the brand to genuine users. So, there must be people out there who have invested their time inthis, and it would be awesome to get some know-how on this.

Comment: You haven't provided us with enough information to answer. What would you consider to be fraudulent activity?

Comment: @Michael- Apologies for the language mix up. Have edited the ques, by fraud I meant fake profiles.   Have also elaborated a bit on the problem.